# Low end GPU with a 250 watt PSU

Tags: graphics-cards, linux, desktop, smps

I apologise in advance if I have posted this in the wrong stackechange site, I wasn't quite sure which to post it on and this one seemed like the best match.

I am looking for a very low end GPU for my 10 year old PC. It would be for running linux and occasional light gaming (Minecraft and maybe some emulation, not exactly sure what I want to do with it yet)! The reason I have decided to not stick with the card integrated to the motherboard is because I would have to downgrade to a very old Linux Kernel version to use the proprietary driver, and the 'nouveau' open source one isn't very good. I just wanted to clarify I'm not expecting (or wanting) a gaming pc, I just wanted to run a newer kernel and have fewer graphical issues.  It's current system specs are as follows:

```
System information report, generated by Sysinfo: 27/05/2019 17:18:20
http://sourceforge.net/projects/gsysinfo

SYSTEM INFORMATION
    Running LinuxMint Linux, the LinuxMint 19.1 (tessa) release.
    GNOME: 3.28.2 (Ubuntu)
    Kernel version: 4.15.0-20-generic (#21-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 24 06:16:15 UTC 2018)
    GCC: 7 (x86_64-linux-gnu)
    Xorg: 1.19.6 (25 October 2018  04:11:27PM) (25 October 2018  04:11:27PM)
    Hostname: jeremy-ixtreme-M3720
    Uptime: 0 days 0 h 49 min

CPU INFORMATION
    GenuineIntel, Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Quad CPU    Q8300  @ 2.50GHz
    Number of CPUs: 4
    CPU clock currently at 2000.092 MHz with 2048 KB cache
    Numbering: family(6) model(23) stepping(10)
    Bogomips: 4999.94
    Flags: fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl cpuid aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm sse4_1 xsave lahf_lm pti tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority dtherm

MEMORY INFORMATION
    Total memory: 7724 MB
    Total swap: 2047 MB

STORAGE INFORMATION
    SCSI device -  scsi3
        Vendor:  ATAPI    
        Model:  DVD A  DH16AASH  
    SCSI device -  scsi4
        Vendor:  ATA      
        Model:  ADATA SU650      
    SCSI device -  scsi6
        Vendor:  Generic  
        Model:  USB SD Reader    
    SCSI device -  scsi6
        Vendor:  Generic  
        Model:  USB CF Reader    

HARDWARE INFORMATION
MOTHERBOARD
    Host bridge
        NVIDIA Corporation MCP73 Host Bridge (rev a2)
        Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] MCP73 Host Bridge
    PCI bridge(s)
        NVIDIA Corporation MCP73 PCI Express bridge (rev a1) (prog-if 01 [Subtractive decode])
        NVIDIA Corporation MCP73 PCI Express bridge (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
        NVIDIA Corporation MCP73 PCI Express bridge (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
        NVIDIA Corporation MCP73 PCI Express bridge (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    ISA bridge
        NVIDIA Corporation MCP73 LPC Bridge (rev a2)
        Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] MCP73 LPC Bridge
    IDE interface
        NVIDIA Corporation MCP73 IDE Controller (rev a1) (prog-if 8a [Master SecP PriP])
        Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] MCP73 IDE Controller

GRAPHIC CARD
    VGA controller
        NVIDIA Corporation C73 [GeForce 7100 / nForce 630i] (rev a2) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] C73 [GeForce 7100 / nForce 630i]

SOUND CARD
    Multimedia controller
        NVIDIA Corporation MCP73 High Definition Audio (rev a1)
        Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] MCP73 High Definition Audio

NETWORK
    Ethernet controller
        Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 01)
        Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
```

Other specs not listed there include:

**250 Watt PSU** (likely awful, the one included in the pre-built. Pretty sure it's *proprietary* too. I understand upgrading this would be hard, though I will do it if it is the only way forward)

**One PCI slot**

**One PCI Express slot**

And I am on a tight budget. I am fine with a card at or under £50, new or second hand. I can check whether the latest Linux kernels support it so you don't have to, but I would imagine most GPUs made within the last 5 years are still supported.

**EDIT**
Currently thinking about one of [these](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/MSI-NVIDIA-GeForce-GTX-750-Ti-2GB-GDDR5-Video-Card-V809-1030R/333216497607?epid=219521256&hash=item4d95403fc7%3Ag%3A1bIAAOSwDuJW0vpw&LH_BIN=1%7C1) or one of [these](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/MSI-GeForce-GT710-2gb-DDR3-Fan-cooled-used-once/153508478957?hash=item23bdd17fed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a 250w psu you won't get far. I think the strongest card you would be able to run is either a Gtx 750 ti, or a RX 460, which will have to be under clocked. Neither of these require an external power cable and pull around 60 watts.

Just make sure your power supply can supply enough amps on the 12v rail, and you should be fine.

Comment: RX 460. It's got open source drivers